# How to use splice and slice correctly

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm not able to figure out the problem in my code. I've read many articles about `slice` and `splice`. I wanted to use them in my Angular project (not both of them together). I'm getting unexpected outputs. Here is my code:

**When using slice:**

```
newArray:string[];
mutatedArray:string[];

removeOneFruit() {
  this.newArray=['Apple', 'Orange', 'Plums', 'Grapes'];
  console.log("Before slicing: "+this.newArray);
  this.mutatedArray=this.newArray.slice(this.newArray.indexOf('Orange'),1);
  console.log("After slicing: "+this.mutatedArray);
}
```

Output:

> Before slicing: Apple,Orange,Plums,Grapes
>
> After slicing:

The After slicing thing is simply blank. No errors or warnings on console. This is strange for me.

**When using splice:**

```
newArray:string[];
mutatedArray:string[];

removeOneFruit() {
  this.newArray=['Apple', 'Orange', 'Plums', 'Grapes'];
  console.log("Before splicing: "+this.newArray);
  this.mutatedArray=this.newArray.splice(this.newArray.indexOf('Orange'),1);
  console.log("After splicing: "+this.mutatedArray);
}
```

Output:

> Before slicing: Apple,Orange,Plums,Grapes
>
> After slicing: Orange

I don't understand what's happening. I'm expecting an array with all the fruits but `Orange`. Please correct me.

PS: Its a miniature model of a huge project where things are not fruits and they ain't hard coded also.

Comment: The index of "Oranges" is 1, and the second parameter is 1, and there is nothing between 1 and 1, so the result is empty. `.splice()` returns an array containing the deleted elements.

Comment: So what should I do. I just want to remove the given value like in this case it is `Orange`. Because in actual it is a dynamic value from some other angular component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.splice()` returns the deleted elements, but if you use it in a separate line:

```js
var arr = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Plums', 'Grapes'];

arr.splice(arr.indexOf('Orange'), 1);

console.log(arr);
```

Or you can use `.slice()` like this: (it's a bit long)

```js
var arr = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Plums', 'Grapes'];

//This slices from the start up to "Orange", then concatenates from after "Orange" to the end of the array
console.log(arr.slice(0, arr.indexOf('Orange')).concat(arr.slice( arr.indexOf('Orange') + 1, arr.length)));
```

Comment: But I'm also doing the same thing. What's the difference.

Comment: `.splice()` is in a new line in my code. Using it in a separate line will remove "Orange" from the array instead of returning "Orange."

Comment: Ok. I'm accepting this for the second answer worked. It's quite long but it is working. I hope my code reviewer will be fine with it. Or else i'll come back to you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

So slice does not work the same as splice

**Array.slice** takes two parameter, *start* and *end*. So in your first function you are giving the start index of Orange and the end index of 1 which I think doesn't make sense because the slice is getting items within a range, so there are no items between that range.

So if you look at the code snippet I have the index of Orange and then the index one up because the slice is inclusive so you in your example Orange is at the 1 index and then you are doing 1 as the end index. So I am pulling everything between index 1 and index 2, which is Orange.

```js
let newArray;
let mutatedArray;

function removeOneFruit() {
  newArray=['Apple', 'Orange', 'Plums', 'Grapes'];
  console.log("Before slicing: "+newArray);
  mutatedArray=newArray.slice(newArray.indexOf('Orange'), newArray.indexOf('Orange')+1);
  console.log("After slicing: "+mutatedArray);
}

removeOneFruit()
```

Your second function you are using **splice** which is used to remove items from an array. **Array.splice**  takes an *index* and *the amount of items you want to remove at that index*. So all you are doing is creating a new array with the item that you remove. If you wanted return an array with everything but Orange. Then you would run **splice**, which would remove Orange,  and then point the mutatedArray to the new value of newArray.

```js
let newArray;
let mutatedArray;

function removeOneFruit() {
  newArray=['Apple', 'Orange', 'Plums', 'Grapes'];
  console.log("Before splicing: "+newArray);
  newArray.splice(newArray.indexOf('Orange'),1);
  mutatedArray= newArray;
  console.log("After splicing: "+mutatedArray);
}

removeOneFruit()
```

Comment: This is surely the best answer. I'm going to use this only. But I've already accepted an answer before yours came in :-(

Comment: That's fine happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Slice is not returning anything because the second parameter is the end index. Since Orange is 1 and the end is 1 it will not return anything.

Splice - will return the deleted items the original array is the one that gets affected.

Answer (score 0):

Read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)!

> `newArray.slice(newArray.indexOf('Orange'), 1);`

This cuts a segment of an array from index `newArray.indexOf('Orange')` (which is `1`) up to but not including index `1`. This ends up as an empty array.

If you wanted a slice of length 2 from a given position, you would do:

```js
var a = [100, 200, 300, 400];
var pos = a.indexOf(200);
a.slice(pos, pos + 2);  // == [ 200, 300 ]
```

If what you need is to remove a particular element from an array, you're better off by just filtering it:

```js
const newArray = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Plums', 'Grapes'];

// Remove the first 'Orange'.
const orangeIx = newArray.indexOf('Orange');
console.log('Removed by index:', 
            newArray.filter((ignoredValue, index) => index != orangeIx));

// Remove every 'Orange'.
console.log('Removed by value:',
            newArray.filter(fruit => fruit != 'Orange'));
```

Note that the above creates a new shallow copy of the original array, not mutates it.

Comment: I just want an array with all the fruits except `Orange`. I want all the remaining values.

Comment: I'm afraid there's much more gymnastic involved in this. I was expecting a simple solution. :-(